# Which prophets in tanach were prosecuted?

Tags: navi-prophets

While, some prophets may be prosecuted. Some don't. I've heard Elisa is actually highly revered while Nehemiah is deplored. Daniel is not prosecuted by jews definitely.

Is there a credible list which prophets are prosecuted and which prophets are not. Are there like lists how each prophets die.

Comment: Uriah and an earlier Zacharias son of Jehoaida the Priest, (not the one one we have writing from) are mentioned by name as being killed. Zacharias by Joash, Uriah by Jehoakim? Jezebel killed thousands of prophets that aren't named ):

Comment: I guess you mean "persecuted" (i.e. afflicted, harassed, punished, or put to death for their troubles), rather than "prosecuted" (i.e. were charged or tried in a court of law).

Comment: Why the downvotes? The comic is actually pro jewish (at least on this part)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any formal, cut-and-dry list, but I own a book called אוצר אישי תנ"ך‏, by יש"י חסידה‏. It is a gold and black book, and is a compendium of named personalities in Tanach, which cites their discussion and appearance all over rabbinic literature, Midrash or Talmud. I bought it at my local judaic bookstore.

It brings sources about their person, lives, and deaths, if there are sources that discuss them outside of the verses. It includes not only prophets, but anyone of note.

It also cites their occurrence in the verses, so if there are no sources that explicitly mention their death or persecution, you can easily find them and in scripture. If hebrew isn't your strong point, I'd recommend The [Artscroll Stone Tanach](http://www.judaism.com/display.asp?etn=BCEBH&gclid=CKij5sHzgLwCFU_NOgodWiEAWQ). It has translation, along with bullet points of important events in the margins, and interesting tidbits in footnotes, all in english.